NextJS app router: Client component with data fetching, inside a suspense boundary gets statically rendered
I have a reproduction for this issue here.
I'm playing around with NextJS app router, and Suspense.
I have two implementations of a simple client component that fetches data with React Query. One uses useSuspenseQuery the other uses a regular query.
export function TodosRq() {

    const query = useQuery<Array<{id: number, title: string}>>({ queryKey: ['todos'], queryFn: async () => {

        await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 10000));
        const res = await  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
        return res.json();
    } })


    return <div>
        {query.data?.map((v) => {
            return <div> 
                RQ
                {v.id} {v.title}
            </div>
        })}
    </div>

}

export function TodosRqSuspense() {

    const query = useSuspenseQuery<Array<{id: number, title: string}>>({ queryKey: ['todos'], queryFn: async () => {

        await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 10000));
        const res = await  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
        return res.json();
    } })


    return <div>
        {query.data.map((v) => {
            return <div> 
                RQ
                {v.id} {v.title}
            </div>
        })}
    </div>

}

In my App router page, I can render  either of these components:
      {/* nb. this suspense boundary won't do anything */}
      <Suspense fallback={'rq loading'}>
        <h2>Todos RQ</h2>
        <TodosRq/>
      </Suspense>

or
      <Suspense fallback={'rq loading'}>
        <h2>Todos RQ</h2>
        <TodosRqSuspense/>
      </Suspense>

Intuitively,  what I'm expecting here is that server render will render application in it's loading state, stream that to the client, and then the client takes over and makes the API call.
However, what I actually observe, is that in the case of using the suspense query, actually NextJS applies static rendering to TodosRqSuspense component. That is, in a production build, it returns prerendered HTML, never making the 10 second wait.
It's important to observe both the behaviour of the dev server, as well as the production build.




Dev Server
Production Build




TodosRq
We don't see the suspense boundary. We wait 10 seconds till content appears. Content does not appear in the root document.
We don't see the suspense boundary. We wait 10 seconds till content appears. Content does not appear in the root document.


TodosRqSuspense
We see the suspense boundary. We wait 10 seconds till content appears. Content appears in the root document. (The dev server appears to do something funny where it can modify the response body of the network request)
We get the content immediately. Content is in the root document.



What am I missing here?
Here's the relevant parts of the documentation and how I understand it:
Static vs Dynamic rendering - for server components default behaviour is that all content will statically rendered (that is, rendered at build time), even if it involves data fetching, unless it fits into one of the exceptions, such as using the cookies or connection methods.
Client components - Client components are pre-rendered on the server, (first render on the server), and but then when they hit the client then the work is done on the client.
Suspense - Allows the 'first render' to show all the loading skeletons etc, and then if using RSCs then they'll stream in, and, this is where I am having some misunderstanding, I would have thought that client components would still do their data fetching client side, and then display when they are complete.
What NextJS recommends - NextJS recommend that you do your data fetching in server components, just to be clear. However - within the context of some kind of migration, it makes sense that we might keep some things as client components. In any case, I'm trying to understand the nuance here.
nb. if we add useSearchParams to our client component, then this behaviour does not occur and behaves inline with how I've intuited.

Relevant github issue here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/56382

in my research Suspense will only work if ppr is enable i m using in my webisite https://codingtricks.co/
it works if i remove ppr it fallback to old way

Checkout react-query documentation - https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/guides/suspense#suspense-on-the-server-with-streaming and https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/reference/useSuspenseQuery
It seems what you have described is expected behavior.

data is guaranteed to be defined. And It can be statically fetched at build time.
Also, as per the first documentation link above, there is a provision to get this working with suspense on server side.

Which part of the documentation suggests that this is expected behavior?

So the question is, when using useSuspenseQuery in NextJS, why it treats the component as a static compoent (ie. only runs once, at build time, and will give the same result for each user), rather than running each time a user views the component.

Hmmm ... For detailed answer I will have to understand the source code of this library... Will take some time

FWIW I think the the same behaviour can be observed using the React 19 use hook as well.

First things first, I would like to explain some concepts to ensure we are on the same page. After that, I will use these concepts to answer your question.
Rendering
Server Components
Render only on the server.
Client Components
Render on both the server and the client.
Streaming

Streaming is built into the Next.js App Router by default, allowing users to see parts of the page immediately before the entire content finishes rendering.
Streaming only happens when there is no route cache on the server.
This is my assumption based on common sense: if the full HTML is already on the server, it can be sent to the client in one pass, eliminating the need for streaming.
Next.js also implies this by stating that streaming occurs when Next.js opts for dynamic rendering.

Render flow
On the server:

React renders Server Components into a special data format called the React Server Component Payload (RSC Payload), which includes references to Client Components.
Next.js uses the RSC Payload and Client Component JavaScript instructions to render HTML for the route on the server.

Then, on the client:

The HTML is used to immediately show a fast non-interactive initial preview of the route.
The React Server Components Payload is used to reconcile the Client and Server Component trees, and update the DOM.
The JavaScript instructions are used to hydrate Client Components and make their UI interactive.

Caching
Cache Layers
The Next.js App Router introduces multiple cache layers that apply to various components of the application, such as data, RSC, and HTML.
My recommendation is to discard the old terms (SSR, CSR, SSG) and instead focus on the render flow of a Next.js application. Ask yourself: which parts of my application are cached? This approach can greatly help understand caching behavior in Next.js.

These are all the cache layers in a Next.js application. However, for this question, you only need to consider the Full Route Cache.
Full Route Cache
The default behavior of Next.js is to cache the rendered result (React Server Component Payload and HTML) of a route on the server. This applies to statically rendered routes at build time, or during revalidation.  It is equivalent to Automatic Static Optimization, Static Site Generation, or Static Rendering.
Static Rendering
Equivalent to Full Route Cache
Dynamic Rendering
Opting out of Full Route Cache by using one of these methods:

Using a Dynamic API such as cookies, headers, connection, draftMode, searchParams prop, unstable_noStore
Using the dynamic = 'force-dynamic' or revalidate = 0 route segment config options
Opting out of the Data Cache.

Fetching
There are four ways of fetching data in a Nextjs app router
Fetch and Resolve on the server
The data will be fetched and the full HTML will be rendered on the server. Both RSC and HTML will then be streamed to the client.
// This is a server component
export default async function Page() {
  const todoList = await fetchTodo();
  return <TodoList todos={todoList}></TodoList>;
}

Fetch on the server and Resolve on the client
The data will be fetched on the server and then streamed to the client as RSC. The HTML will be rendered on the client.
// This is a server component
export default async function Page() {
  const todoPromise = fetchTodo();
  // TodoListWrapper is a client component that use streamed data from the server
  return <TodoListWrapper todoPromise={todoPromise}></TodoListWrapper>
}

// TodoListWrapper is a client component that uses streamed data from the server
"use client";
function TodoListWrapper({ todoPromise }: { todoPromise: Promise<Array<Todo>> }) {
  const todo = use(todoPromise);
  return <TodoList todos={todo}></TodoList>;
}

Fetch and Resolve on the client
The data will be fetched and the full HTML will be rendered on the client
"use client"
export default function Page() {
  const [data, setData] = useState()
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchTodo().then(setData)
  }, [])
  return <TodoList todos={data}></TodoList>
}

Duplicating. Fetch and Resolve on the server and then Fetch and Resolve on the client
The data will be fetched and the full HTML will be rendered on the server, then they will be fetched and rendered on the client again. This might sound crazy, but it's actually what useSuspenseQuery is doing.
"use client"
export default function UseSuspenseQueryPage() {
  const query = useSuspenseQuery<Array<Todo>>({
    queryKey: ["todos"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      return await fetchTodo();
    },
  });
  return <TodoList todos={query.data}></TodoList>
}

Understanding all of the above concepts is crucial to grasp the behavior of a Next.js application. Now, putting all of them together to answer your question.
Answer
I created a small site to demonstrate how all these things work together. You can check it out here.

Github
Live Demo

This table shows the behavior of each route. Since almost all the optimizations in Next.js happen in the production build, we only need to consider the behavior of the production build.



No
Technique
Full Route Cache
Streaming
Fetching Data
Resolve Data




1
fetch
Yes
No
Server
Server


2
fetch + dynamic rendering
No
Yes
Server
Server


3
use
Yes
No
Server
Client


4
use + dynamic rendering
No
Yes
Server
Client


5
useEffect
Yes
No
Client
Client


6
useQuery
Yes
No
Client
Client


7
useSuspenseQuery
Yes
No
Both
Both


8
useSuspenseQuery + useSearchParams
Yes
No
Client
Client


9
useSyncExternalStore
Yes
No
Both
Both


10
useSyncExternalStore + useSearchParams
Yes
No
Client
Client




Tip: To determine if a page is streamed, observe the browser's loading indicator and the timing of the document request. If the loading indicator remains active while the data is loading, and the HTML request time updates after the data is loaded (usually more than 5 seconds), then the page is streamed.

Explaination

No. 1 and No. 2: These use fetch directly in server components with async/await, fetching and resolving the data on the server. Streaming is used when there is no Full Route Cache, i.e., during dynamic rendering.
No. 3 and No. 4: These use React.use in client components to resolve data fetched on the server. Streaming is used when there is no Full Route Cache, i.e., during dynamic rendering.
No. 5 and No. 6: These fetch data only on the client. The route is still pre-rendered and cached on the server with fallback data.
No. 7: This uses useSuspenseQuery to fetch data on both the server and the client. Open the browser's console log to check if the data is still being fetched. useSuspenseQuery throws a promise to force the component to suspend on the server, making the renderer wait for the data before returning the HTML to the client. This is why the route is pre-rendered with full data.
No. 8: This is similar to No. 7, except it uses useSearchParams, causing the Client Component tree up to the closest Suspense boundary to be client-side rendered. In this case, the whole page will be client-side rendered. The route is still pre-rendered and cached with the fallback being loading.tsx. It might seem like streaming, but it is actually pre-rendered with a fallback on the server while fetching data on the client.
No. 9 and No. 10: I tried to reproduce the behavior of  useSuspenseQuery with useSyncExternalStore and throwing a promise. These share the same behavior with No. 7 and No. 8.

Conclution
To migrate from React Query in the Page Router to the App Router, you should use useQuery with React.use to fetch the data on the server and resolve it on the client. This minimizes effort and prevents duplicate data fetching.
function TodoList({ query }: { query: UseQueryResult<Todo[]> }) {
  const data = React.use(query.promise)

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((todo) => (
        <li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export function App() {
  const query = useQuery({ queryKey: ['todos'], queryFn: fetchTodos })

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Todos</h1>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <TodoList query={query} />
      </React.Suspense>
    </>
  )
}

For the long run, I recommend removing React Query from the Next.js App Router and using fetch directly in server components. It's not that Next.js is better than TanStack, it's just that the Next.js App Router introduces many optimization and caching layers for fetching, which might overlap with React Query and add unnecessary complexity when used together.
